# haskell - the type of join function

Tags: haskell, monads

```
data M a = M a deriving (Show)
unitM a = M a
bindM (M a) f = f a

joinM :: M (M a) -> M a
joinM m = m `bindM` id

joinM' :: M a -> a
joinM' m = m `bindM` id
```

---

Note that `joinM (M 0)` will fail to type check, whereas `joinM' (M 0)` will be fine.

My question: why is `joinM` defined as `M (M a) -> M a` but not as `M a -> a`?

From my understanding,
`unitM` puts the value `a` into the monad `M a`
`joinM` gets the value `a` from the monad `M a`

So `joinM` should really work on any monad, i.e., not necessarily nested ones such as `M (M a)`, right?

Comment: `joinM` is defined like that because that's how you declared its type: `joinM :: M (M a) -> M a`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes. But why is `joinM` not defined like `joinM'`?

Comment: `joinM` _is_ defined like `joinM'`. The reason `joinM (M 0))` doesn't type check is because `M 0` has type `M Int` and not `M (M Int)` required by `joinM`. However this example doesn't generalise to all `Monad`s since `bindM` has the wrong type, it needs to have type `M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b`. In general there's no way to write `joinM'` for all monads.

Comment: Is your question actually about monads and the `join` operation they provide? If so, consider the difference between `[[a]] -> [a]` and `[a] -> a`. One of those has any number of simple, total definitions. The other has zero simple, total definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of monads is that you *can't* get a value out of them. If `join` had type `m a -> a` then the `IO` monad would be perfectly useless, since you could just extract the values freely. The point of monads is that you can chain computations together (`>>=` can be defined in terms of `join`, provided you have `return` and `fmap`) and put values into a monadic context, but you *can't* (in general) get them out.

In your specific case, you've defined what is essentially the identity monad. In that case, it's easy to extract the value; you just strip away the layer of `M` and move on with your life. But that's not true for general monads, so we restrict the type of `join` so that more things can be monads.

Your `bindM` is not of the correct type, by the way. The general type of `>>=` is

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Your function has type

```
bindM :: M a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

Notice that your type is more general. Hence, again, in your *specific* case, you can get away with being looser on the requirements of `joinM`, whereas specific monads cannot. Try giving `bindM` an explicit type signature of `M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b` and then see if both of your join functions still typecheck.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I see the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Given a type constructor `M :: * -> *`, and a type `a`, consider the following sequence of types

```
a, M a, M (M a), M (M (M a)), ...
```

If we have polymorphic functions `return :: b -> M b` and `extract :: M b -> b` (your alternative `join`), we can convert a value of any type above to any other type above. Indeed, we can add and remove `M` as wanted using these two functions, choosing the type `b` suitably. In more casual words, we can move both to the *right* and to the *left* in such type sequence.

In a monad, instead, we can move to the *right* without limits (using `return`). We can also move to the *left* almost everywhere: the important exception being that we can not move from `M a` to `a`. This is realized by `join :: M (M c) -> M c`, which has the type of `extract :: M b -> b` restricted to the case `b = M c`. So essentially, we can move *left* (as with `extract`), but only when we end up in a type which has at least one `M` -- hence, no further to the left than `M a`.

As Carl mentions above in the comments this restriction makes it possible to have more monads. For instance, if `M = []` is the list monad, we can properly implement `return` and `join` but not `extract`.

```
return :: a -> [a]
return x = [x]

join :: [[a]] -> [a]
join xss = concat xss
```

Instead `extract :: [a] -> a` can not be a total function, since `extract [] :: a` would be well typed, yet tries to extract a value of type `a` from the empty list. It is a well-known theoretical result that no total expression can have the polymorphic type `... :: a`. We can have `undefined :: a`, `fromJust Nothing :: a`, or `head [] :: a` but all of these are not total, and will raise an error when evaluated.